# Convert Dictionary to xml with proper format?

Tags: xml, powershell

The following script

```
$d = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[int, bool]'
$d.Add(1, $true)
$d.Add(2, $false)
($d | ConvertTo-Xml).DocumentElement.OuterXml
```

returns

```
<Objects>
  <Object Type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Boolean]">
    <Property Name="Key" Type="System.Int32">1</Property>
    <Property Name="Value" Type="System.Boolean">True</Property>
    <Property Name="Key" Type="System.Int32">2</Property>
    <Property Name="Value" Type="System.Boolean">False</Property>
  </Object>
</Objects>
```

However, can it return the following?

```
<Objects>
  <Object Key="1" Value="True" />
  <Object Key="2" Value="False" />
</Objects>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`ConvertTo-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-xml) (the in-memory counterpart to [`Export-CliXml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml), albeit with a [different output format](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8311)), the *closest approximation* of the desired format requires adding the `-NoTypeInformation` switch, which gives you the equivalent of:

```
<Objects>
  <Object>
    <Property Name="Key">1</Property>
    <Property Name="Value">True</Property>
    <Property Name="Key">2</Property>
    <Property Name="Value">False</Property>
  </Object>
</Objects>
```

---

**To get the desired output**, you'll have to **create the XML *manually***:

```
$d.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { '<Objects>' } {
    '  <Object Key="{0}" Value="{1}" />' -f $_.Key, $_.Value
  } { '</Objects>'}
```

Note the need to use `.GetEnumerator()` in order to send the key-value pairs individually through the pipeline; by default, PowerShell doesn't enumerate hashtable/dictionary entries in the pipeline.

Comment: I was trying to convert the dictionary to PowerShell collection and then convert it to XML using `convertto-xml` to avoid string manipulation.

Comment: @ca9163d9: Understandable, but string manipulation is simplest in this case; `ConvertTo-Xml` / `Export-CliXml` are for as-faithful-as-possible serialization of objects, which is not always the most readable format.